# What is the meaning of these seals?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

What is the meaning of these seals?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Seal transcription]

They are two names:

- （汪）寅仙
- 張守（智）

They are the names of two (apparently) well-known [*Yíxīng* ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yixing_ware) artisans, who have jointly designed some pottery sets.

You can use [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E6%B1%AA%E5%AF%85%E4%BB%99+%E5%BC%B5%E5%AE%88%E6%99%BA&hl=en&gl=ar&tbm=isch) to get an idea of their products.

Comment: `Thank You` @dROOOze